# Unresolved reference: xms. Huawei Xms adaption layer is not working

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

I'm trying to add a G+H solution for my app. I've done conversion from HMS toolkit. But after the conversion, it gives me error on xms imports also it's give me error regarding

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not find com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms-plugin:1.5.1.300.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/huawei/agconnect/agconnect-apms-plugin/1.5.1.300/agconnect-apms-plugin-1.5.1.300.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/huawei/agconnect/agconnect-apms-plugin/1.5.1.300/agconnect-apms-plugin-1.5.1.300.pom
> - https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/huawei/agconnect/agconnect-apms-plugin/1.5.1.300/agconnect-apms-plugin-1.5.1.300.pom
> Required by:
> project :

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be due to your APM plugin. Try changing it to  `classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms-plugin:1.4.1.306'` may solve your issue.

[image]

For Details,check [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-apms-apmsplugin?ha_source=hms1).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solutions.

Make sure

1. Class path specified

   classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.1.301'
   classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms-plugin:1.2.1.301'
2. Apply these plugins

   apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
   apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect.apms'